# Regarding fastRemove() method in ArrayList class

Tags: java, collections

I was going through Array List class in decomplier have found this method..

```
private void fastRemove(int paramInt)
  {
    this.modCount += 1;
    int i = this.size - paramInt - 1;
    if (i > 0)
      System.arraycopy(this.elementData, paramInt + 1, this.elementData, paramInt, i);
    this.elementData[(--this.size)] = null;
  }
```

I just want to know the in which condition do we really required the fastRemove() method, Please provide example so that understanding can be clear

[image]

Comment: Where did you find a such a method in ArrayList ? If I'm not getting wrong there is no such a method.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 2):

The user would never call that method directly (hence the keyword `private`). `fastRemove()` is what actually does the removing when `remove(Object o)` is called.

Answer (score 2):

From the comment for this method:

> Private remove method that skips bounds checking and does not return
>   the value removed.

As you might've seen, this is internally called by the `public` `remove()` method. If you look at the source-code for this method, you can clearly decipher when this and why this `fastRemove()` method is called:

```
public boolean remove(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        if (elementData[index] == null) {
            fastRemove(index);
            return true;
        }
    } else {
        for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
        if (o.equals(elementData[index])) {
            fastRemove(index);
            return true;
        }
        }
    return false;
}
```

The idea of having this method is simple: Don't perform any bound check and internally rearrange the array.

Answer (score 0):

`fastRemove(...)` is a private method used in the `ArrayList` class which is used by the `remove` method in the class. As `fastRemove` is a private method, you can't use this. However you can use `remove` method which uses this method. From the summary of `remove` method:-

```
Removes the first occurrence of the specified element from this list,
if it is present.  If the list does not contain the element, it is
unchanged.
```